# Secure Web API data from tools like fiddler

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler

How can I protect the data my service provides to my application from tools like Fiddler? Or at least prevent someone making many requests to my service (like maximum requests per minute, IP/MAC Address blacklist, etc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent data-scraping a valuable data web service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350298/how-to-prevent-data-scraping-a-valuable-data-web-service)

Comment: I would recommend looking into this conversation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817300/how-to-throttle-requests-in-a-webapi-controller/23750174#23750174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Throttling Handler for ASP.NET Web API announced by Stefan Prodan recently. Details can be found in the [article here](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2013/12/asp-net-web-api-throttling-handler/).